# LyX | Automatic Wrap by Preview?

Tags: lyx, code, live-preview

I haven't found a question post about this exact thing - please link me to one if you do:

Is it possible in LyX to set-up Wrap By Preview for TeX code (written in those TeX code boxes)? I want to set-up something that similar to Instant Preview, only for TeX.

Right now, the only way that I know of to see inside a LyX document the generated is by right-clicking on a TeX box, and clicking on `Wrap by Preview`.
I want to automate that with maybe some script that can be written for LyX (or something simpler, if it's possible).

Comment: Maybe here's a better place to ask: https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists

Answer (score 2):

It is on purpose that there is no automatic way of doing this. ERT boxes are often incomplete by themselves. For example, I might have the ERT box:

```
\textbf{
```

then I have some text, then in another ERT box:

```
}
```

For more information, see [this](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9468) enhancement request.

Note that you can create a shortcut that opens a TeX box and wraps it in preview. That way one shortcut can do both of those things.